How can I set a branch specifier for branches and tags based on a job parameter?
My git repo has a declarative Jenkinsfile that is used to build the software in the repo. I want to build either the main branch or tags that are of the form release/<version>. My goal is to have a string parameter refname for the Jenkins job that is set to either main or <version>.
According to Jenkins documentation I can use this parameter (as an environment variable) to set a "Branch specifier" in the "Branches to build" section of the configuration. If I set my branch specifier to /refs/heads/${refname} this works for building the main branch. To build a release tag, I have to set the branch specifier to /refs/tags/${refname}. I can't have both settings at the same time.
How can I set the branch specifier to either /refs/heads/... or refs/tags/... based on the value of the $refname parameter?
Is there any way to process a job parameter before it is used as a branch specifier in a job configuration? I tried adding a Groovy function to the Jenkinsfile to postprocess the $refname parameter, but wasn't successful. Probablx because the environment block isn't evaluated until the Jenkinsfile is interpreted during job execution – and then it's too late.
This is my Jenkinsfile (albeit shortened):
pipeline {
      
    parameters {
        string(
            name: 'refname',
            defaultValue: 'main',
            description: 'main or name of release/ tag.')
    }
    
    environment {
        buildref = GET_BUILDREF(refname)
    }
    
    stages {
        
        stage('build software') {
            steps {
                // deleted steps here
            }
        }        

        stage('Process Result HEAD (Intranet)') {
            when {
                expression { params.refname == 'main' }
            }
            steps {
                // deleted steps here
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Process Result Release (NAS)') {
            when {
                expression { params.refname != 'main' }
            }
            steps {
                // deleted steps here
            }
        }
    } //stages
    
   String GET_BUILDREF(refname) {
      if ("main" == refname)
         return "refs/heads/"+refname
      else
         return "refs/tags/"+refname
   }
 
}

I tried the git parameter plugin, but couldn't get it to work properly. I assume it wouldn't solve the problem with the branch specifier, though.
Switching to revisions in the pipeline is not what I have in mind. The Jenkinsfile specifies the version of the build system (a Docker image), so that there is a relation between a revision of the software and the version of the build system.
If I always start with the most current Jenskinsfile from origin/main then the version of the build system is the one that matches origin/main and not -- for example -- release/v2.1.2. To achieve this, I'd have to start with the Jenkinsfile obtained from release/v2.1.2.
My current workaround is to have two jobs: one for building "main", one for building releases. Both configs are identical except for a single word "heads" or "refs" in the branch specifier. That seems a bit much.
